# Query efficiency in update with two tables

Tags: sql-server, updates

I wrote the following update

```
update menus_pages
set parent_page_id = (select pages.page_id from tb_pages pages where pages.name = 'ADM')
where page_id = (select pages.page_id from tb_pages pages where pages.name = 'CAL')
```

and it works well but....there is a more efficient way to update that table on SQLSERVER?

Thanks

Comment: What do you mean, more efficient? Is there a problem with the query you have?

Comment: I mean faster...and no, there isn't any problem, but if there is a better way to do it I want to know it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do this with joins. But this only works if there is exact one record in tb_pages for name = 'ADM' and exact one record with name = 'CAL'... (But the query in your question works only under these conditions too)

```
UPDATE  mp
SET     mp.parent_page_id = ADM.page_id
FROM    menu_pages mp
        INNER JOIN tb_pages CAL
            ON mp.page_id = CAL.page_id
            AND CAL.name = 'CAL'
        INNER JOIN tb_pages ADM
            ON ADM.name = 'ADM'
```

Comment: Just want to add that one must be especially careful using the `UPDATE...FROM` proprietary syntax to ensure no more than one row qualifies the join clauses.  Unlike the correlated subquery method, this will not raise the `subquery returned more than one value` error so the result is non-deterministic when more than one row is returned.

Comment: exactly - that's what i wanted to say, it only works correct if there is only one row for CAL and ADM. You're right, you will get no error message when using joins...but i don't like correlated subqueries as they are much slower in most cases ;-)

Comment: that's what I wanted! thanks! and yes, .name is unique

Comment: @Thal Do note that this most likely will not be any faster than your original query. Subquery that simply returns a single constant value isn't anything expensive, really.

Comment: I know @Luaan , but now i know how to use it in more complex queries where the use of inner joins could have a significant improvement in speed

Answer (score 0):

are page_id and pages.name the primary keys ?

If not try using your primary keys in your where clause if you can.

If you can't use your primary keys in the where clauses, add an index to page_id and pages.name.

http://sql.sh/cours/index/create